# Can you run version 0.2.3 and 1.0.0 of the spotify apps api at the same time in the same app?

Tags: spotify

Can you run version 0.2.3 and 1.0.0 of the Spotify apps api at the same time in the same app? This would be really **really** helpfull for me during the development process in order to migrate our current Spotify-app from 0.2.3 to the new 1.0.0 api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry but that it's not possible. The API version that your app uses is defined in the `Dependencies` section of your `manifest.json` file.

You can create a copy of your app, changing its `BundleIdentifier`, and try to isolate the code that is depending on the Spotify API, modularize it and port it step by step.

Comment: How would isoation help me port our app step by step? The modules depending on the old api would not be runnable anyway.

Comment: Is it impossible for you to just make the old "getSpotifyApi()" available from the new api?

Comment: Isolation will help you to keep code that is not dependent on Spotify API separated from the Spotify API calls. This is a rebuilt API and there is no backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yes but it would still not help me rewrite our app step by step. I would still have a huge chunck of non-working code that would have to be rewritten in one mega step. Is there a reason why no backwards compability is provided?